# How to identify what key handler is "eating" key presses

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, keypress, keydown, keyup

I have a fairly complicated React app with a number of different key up/key down/key press handlers. On one particular page, the Tab key does not work to move between any elements on the screen. I would assume one of the key press events is receiving the press erroneously, but I don't want to rip apart the app by temporarily removing them all and adding them back one by one.

Is there a way, using one of the major browsers' devtools or some other mechanism, to identify what key event is consuming the key press?